# Как вращать точку в системе координат?

Tags: c++, opengl

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю кое-что на OpenGL, нужно вращать фигуру вокруг оси, допустим Х, без использования glRotatef().

То есть пользователь задает угол, допустим, angle, и мне нужна функция, которая получая угол и значения 3 координат точки, возвращает 3 других значения, новые координаты точки после перемещения на заданный угол.

Как реализовать такое на C++/C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если Вы умете умножать матрицу к вектору, то формула проста:

Есть три матрицы вращения:

1) Вращение вокруг оси х

[image]

2) Вращение вокруг оси у

[image]

3) Вращение вокруг оси z

[image]

Соответсвенно, умножив вектор, то есть координаты точки на эти матрицы мы получим новые координаты точки.

v - координаты начальные;
M - матрица вращения;
V - новые координаты;

```
for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
{
  for(int j = 1; j<=3; j++)
  {
     V[i]+=M[i][j] * v[j];
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
V[1] новая координата по Х
V[2] новая координата по У
V[3] новая координата по Z
```